# How to sort by an unordered list alphabetically?

Tags: html, laravel

I need your help.I'm trying for 1 hour to sort an unordered list alphabetically but all I have tried doesn't working.

Here is my code

```
@foreach($users->contact as $user)
    <ul style="list-style: none;right: 40px; position: relative" id="destPopuler">
    @if( $user->role[0]->pivot->role_id == 1 )
       <li class="country"><input class="my_div" id="{{$user->username}}" name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->id }}" <?php if(isset($replyMessage)){ if($replyMessage == $user->id) { echo "selected"; } } ?>><span style="padding: 5px" class="name">{{ $user->username }}</span></li>
    @endif
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

This returns me :

```
Andrey2234
Test andrei45
Stefan MB
```

Here is what I tried. :

```
var activeLanguage = "de"

function sortUL(selector) {
var $ul = $(selector);
$ul.find('li').sort(function (a, b) {
    var upA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var upB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    return (upA < upB) ? -1 : (upA > upB) ? 1 : 0;
}).appendTo(selector);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
sortUL("#destPopuler");
});
```

or

```
function sortList(ul) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(ul);

  Array.from(ul.getElementsByTagName("LI"))
    .sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent))
    .forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li));
}

sortList("destPopuler");
```

Comment: Please click `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] WITHOUT PHP/Laravel. It is not a PHP question at all. Also it looks like you have a UL per person

Comment: Also a checkbox is checked, not selected

Comment: When I replicate your code with normal html ul the top code works

Comment: @Dumisani do you know why mine isn't working...?

Comment: @mplungjan yep, you right. The problem was that I have UL per person.That was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @mplungjan I just took out the UL from `foreach` and that's it.

Comment: That is why it is MUCH better to not have any PHP in a jQuery question. If you had posted a [mcve] with the view-source HTML we had fixed it even quicker or you would have not even needed to ask

Comment: @mplungjan, you are right. Next time I will erase all PHP from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work for me if I have an LI per person instead of UL per person

You should also wrap the sort in a `$(function() {})`

```js
function sortList(ul) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(ul);

  Array.from(ul.getElementsByTagName("LI"))
    .sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent))
    .forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li));
}

$(function() { // run on page load
  sortList("destPopuler");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="list-style: none;right: 40px; position: relative" id="destPopuler">
  <li class="country">
    <input class="my_div" id="NAME2" name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="ID2"><span style="padding: 5px" class="name">NAME2</span></li>
  <li class="country">
    <input class="my_div" id="NAME3" name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="ID3"><span style="padding: 5px" class="name">NAME3</span></li>
  <li class="country">
    <input class="my_div" id="NAME1" name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="ID1"><span style="padding: 5px" class="name">NAME1</span></li>
</ul>
```

PHP:

```
<ul style="list-style: none;right: 40px; position: relative" id="destPopuler">
@foreach($users->contact as $user)
  @if( $user->role[0]->pivot->role_id == 1 )
   <li class="country"><input class="my_div" id="{{$user->username}}" name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->id }}" <?php if(isset($replyMessage)){ if($replyMessage == $user->id) { echo "selected"; } } ?>><span style="padding: 5px" class="name">{{ $user->username }}</span></li>
  @endif
@endforeach
</ul>
```